# sleep or wait()

Tags: wait, thread-sleep

Suppose that you have two threads using synchronized methods to share a buffer, one method for writing to the buffer and one for reading from it. If the reader thread finds the buffer empty, explain which it would be more appropriate for the reader to use: sleep or wait.

Comment: What distinguishes sleep() from wait()? What is the reader thread trying to accomplish? Given these facts, what is your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a lot like homework, so I will only give a hint.

Take a look regarding how locks are managed during wait and sleep. The javadoc for both of them will explain the difference.

[wait](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29)
[sleep](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)

Comment: How do you know it's java-related ?

Comment: I don't, I guessed since it the most common language for beginners classes in programming, and that the text fits Java context/sematics quite well. Could be related to another programming language, but I still bet my 5 cents on Java :)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly homework so a hint:

Ask yourself, if you were to choose to sleep how long should you sleep for? What happens if you choose a timeout that's too small, and what happens if it's too large?

Conversely, how long does it take for the buffer to be filled? Is it ok for the application to buffer data for a short time or does it need that data ASAP?